# Session data could not be access on loading but fine when reload the same page in node.js

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, express-session

I'm a beginner playing with sessions authentication in node.js. It almost work fine at my level that,

- session got initialized when user logged in
- session got stored inside database on logged in and deleted when logged out.
- session expired within a period i want.
- problem: I wanna render user email through `res.render('admin',{user})`in view but it disappear on loading(logged in) and appeared as soon as i reload the same view page. It seems like condition `if(req.session.userEmail)` in ***routes/pages.js*** is `false` when loading but `true` when reload the same page. In short on loading `else` part in ***routes/pages.js*** is viewed only but when reload stuff under `if condition` is viewed at client side. Why it is appeared on reload not on loading?? please help.
- ***routes/pages.js***

```js
const express= require('express');
const { removeAllListeners } = require('nodemon');
const router=express.Router();

router.get('/views/admin', (req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.session);
  if(req.session.userEmail){

      res.render('admin', {user});
      
  }else{
    res.send('<p>Session Expired. Click <a href="/views/login">here</a> to login</p>');   
  }  
});
```

**

- *log on load*

**

```js
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: true
  }
}
```

- ***log on reload***

```js
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: true
  },
  userEmail: 'pdm@gmail.com'
}
```

- ***routes/auth.js***

```js
const express= require('express');
const authController= require('../controller/auth');
const router= express.Router();
router.post('/signup',authController.signup);
router.post('/login',authController.login);
router.post('/logout',authController.logout);
module.exports=router;
```

`

- ***controller/auth.js***

```js
const router = require('../routes/auth');
const bycrypt= require('bcryptjs');

exports.login= (req, res)=>{

    const {email,password}=req.body;

    myPool.query('SELECT*FROM userinfo WHERE uemail=?' ,[email],(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else if(rows.length>0){
            bycrypt.compare(password,(rows[0].upwd),(err,success)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(success);//print fine
                    if(success==false||rows[0].uemail!==email){
                        return res.render('login',{
                            message:'Incorrect Password'
                        });
                    }else {
                        var sessUser=req.session;
                        sessUser.userEmail=email;
                        console.log(sessUser.userEmail)//print fine
                        if(sessUser.userEmail){
                            res.redirect('../views/admin');
                        }
                       }  
                }
            })
    }else{
        return res.render('login',{
            message:'This Email does not exist'
        })
    }
            
});
}
```

---

- log

---

```js
true
pdm@gmail.com
```

***index.js***

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mySqlStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const {
  request
} = require('https');
const app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.url, req.session && req.session.userEmail); next();})//it print current 'url' and 'undefined'
dotenv.config({
  path: './.env'
});
const options = {
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'logindb',
  createDatabaseTable: true
}
myPool = mysql.createPool(options);
const sessionStore = new mySqlStore(options, myPool);
app.use(session({
  name: process.env.SESS_NAME,
  secret: 'my secret',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: true
  }
}));
const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './public');
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use('/', require('./routes/pages'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.listen(8084, () => console.log('Server is running at port:8084'));
exports.store = sessionStore;
```

---

- All logs

---

```js
Server is running at port:8084
---before login---
/views/login undefined
/style.css undefined

---On login---
/auth/login undefined
/views/admin undefined

---On reload after login---
/views/admin undefined
/style.css undefined

---On logout---
/auth/logout undefined
/views/login undefined
/style.css undefined
```

Comment: You say: *"I wanna render user email through res.render('admin',{user})in view but it disappear on loading(logged in)"*.  What exactly disappears?  All `res.render()` does it return some HTML as a response to an http request.  That, by itself, has nothing to do with a session.  So, what request and from where are you saying losses the session?  We need the exact sequence of events that your server sees and need to know how these are triggered in the client.  If ANY of these are `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` calls from the front-end, we need to see that code too. So far, not enough info here.

Comment: mate 'res.render()' returns html but i passed it  'user' variable in option to get its value in 'admin.hbs'.  Problem is that the if condition in routes/pages.js returns 'false' due to which else part of the same condition get executed but at the same time session get initialized and stored inside database. As soon as i reload the page stuff under if condition get executed that is res.render returns HTML and value of 'user' variable as well.  I just wants that the thing happened after reload , the same thing should on single loading i.e when user click on login button

Comment: now i include 'index.js' and 'admin.hbs'

Comment: i can send you screenshots if you provide me your email please?? It will gives you more clarification on my problem.

Comment: Please add this as your very first middleware (before any other middleware): `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.url, req.session && req.session.userEmail); next();})`, then capture those logs and add them to your question.  I need to see EXACTLY what requests are arriving on your server and in what order.  On stackoverflow, we keep everything for the question here in the question, not via private email.  If you can clarify something with screenshots, then add them to your question.

Comment: FYI, in case you were thinking of screenshots of code, that's not the proper procedure on Stackoverflow.  Code should be pasted into the question as text, not as images.

Comment: mate did so means i add    app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.url, req.session && req.session.userEmail); next();})    but it gives undefined. Moreover i updated my all code snippets, hope it will help in rectifying my issue

Comment: If you implemented my debugging suggestion properly, it would output a lot more than `undefined`.  I want to see exactly what it outputs when you have this problem.  I want to see ALL the output.  It should be showing all the request URLs that are being used in this process.  That's what I need to see.  From your question I don't understand the sequence of events that leads to the problem so I was hoping to see this output so I could understand.  If you're not going to help me understand, then I can just move on to other questions.

Comment: sorry i couldnt follow your instructions correctly. Now i added all logs that i mentioned in my all snippets including app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.url, req.session && req.session.userEmail); next();}) in index,js. please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not obvious what is going on.  It could be a timing issue where the redirect after login is arriving back on your server BEFORE the session data gets successfully saved in your database.  You can eliminate that possibility by changing this:

```
var sessUser=req.session;
sessUser.userEmail=email;
console.log(sessUser.userEmail)//print fine
if(sessUser.userEmail){
    res.redirect('../views/admin');
}
```

to this:

```
var sessUser = req.session;
sessUser.userEmail = email;
console.log(sessUser.userEmail);
req.session.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("session save error", err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
        res.redirect('../views/admin');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir its working smoothly in all routes without reload. Can you please explain or suggest a blog/ tutorial on why this issue occurred??. Or what concept can i adopt with this? Bundle of thanks

Comment: @AliRaza - I have never quite understood the "autosave" capabilities in express-session and when you can rely on it and when you can't, but since saving into your database is non-blocking and asynchronous and autosave doesn't happen until AFTER the request is done and the redirect response causes that same browser to make an immediate new request, it makes sense that if you redirect before the session autosaves your changes, then the new redirected request might arrive too soon before the session has finished updating the saved session object in your database.

Comment: @AliRaza - So, I think the general rule is that if you're using an actual database store for the session and you have to make sure the session updates are written before the client might do something after this response, then save the session manually BEFORE sending the response.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for this great help. its done